# Google TV Emulator - Google Maps Support

Tags: google-tv

I am trying to run Google TV Maps example on Google TV Emulator. I am facing an issue as the emulator does not contain the google maps application required to run the app.

Does Google TV support google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google TV emulator does not have all the standard Google TV apps included with it. A real Google TV does support Google Maps as well as a lot of other things you will not be able to do with the emulator. If you are building apps targeting Google TV (porting a Tablet app or writing a new one) I would encourage you to get a Google TV device.

Comment: Just to clarify you can use Maps via the API it is not an installed application - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/